# What are the food specialties of Charleston, South Carolina?

Tags: food-and-drink, local-cuisine

Two of the things I really like about traveling are trying the local food, and having good food (often, but not always, the same thing). What are the food specialties of Charleston, South Carolina? I recently read that Charleston is [one of the best food cities in the USA](http://www.washingtonpost.com/sf/style/2015/04/07/the-search-for-americas-best-food-cities-charleston-s-c/) and I would like to know what's important to try on a trip there.

Unfortunately, just being "good" doesn't really narrow things down. I figure the best way to do this is to order by specificity, so if there's a dish that's legendary for being served at one particular restaurant (like [half smokes at Ben's Chili Bowl](http://benschilibowl.com/store/bens-classic-half-smokes/) in Washington, DC) it should go at the top of the list, followed by specific famous restaurants (e.g. [Noma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noma_(restaurant))), then city specialties, then regional.

I guess for the purposes of this question, a specialty would be a food that I wouldn't be able to get anywhere else or wouldn't be prepared in the same way elsewhere.

Comment: Color me confused. You linked to a Washington Post article about how great the food is in Charleston, and the article lists several well known eateries in the city. And you came here to ask people to list places to eat in the city? Hat hunting?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is both asking for the 'best' (subjective) and a list question; both of which are on the what not to ask list in the help center

Comment: @CGCampbell you are right that the article lists a number of eateries, but I don't know how well if at all the listed locations correlate with the criteria I laid out. A bit of Googling and some brief conversations with acquaintances who are more familiar with that area than I am make me think that the article, while good in many ways, is not well-suited to answering my particular question.

Comment: As for hats, it's much easier for me to get those on other sites. I'm not a travel expert by any means. I asked this question because I actually want an answer.

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis see above

Comment: As for the close vote, fair enough. I was kind of on the fence about asking here, for that very reason. But every site has its own standards for how much opinionation is allowed, and I thought this was one of the more relaxed ones. If I was wrong about that and the community votes to close, I'll respect that. Certainly you can't deny that regional food specialties are a thing that exists and may be of interest to travelers, whether you find the setup of my particular question constructive or not.

Comment: Hmm.. Perhaps asking for regional specialties and representative restaurants serving them would be acceptable--rather like the Italian street food question--instead of just requesting a list of "good" restaurants, which seems more subjective?

Comment: I think we can answer the specialty part of the question but not the restaurant recommendation one. I'll edit the latter out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're after is [**Low country cuisine**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowcountry_cuisine) - the cooking associated with the area.

> **Appetizers, soups, and salads**
>
> ```
> Benne-Oyster Soup
> Cooter Soup (Turtle Soup)
> She-crab soup
> Sweet Potato & Crab Soup
> Gumbo (Okra Soup)
> Brunswick Stew
> ```
>
> **Meat and seafood**
>
> ```
> Catfish stew
> Lowcountry Boil
> Country Captain
> Frogmore Stew
> Shrimp and grits
> Shrimp Kedgeree
> Oyster Roast
> Crab cake
> ```
>
> **Rice**
>
> ```
> Charleston Red Rice
> Perlau or chicken bog
> Salmon and rice
> ```
>
> **Sides**
>
> ```
> Hoppin' John
> Fried Cabbage
> Baked Mac-n-Cheese
> ```

Wikipedia goes on to explain that the geography is the main factor in distinguishing the region's culinary identity from other areas of the South. There's an abundance of shrimp, fish, crabs, and oysters in the estuary system, and the marshlands of South Carolina are also conducive to growing rice, and that grain has become a major part of the everyday diet over time.